# How to call a SP with a list of GUID's as a one parameter in MYSQL using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I need to use a list of GUID's in a where condition. How do I call that stored procedure with parameter?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetIds`(IN ID VARCHAR(300) )
BEGIN

    select distinct S.TaxonId from skills S
    JOIN goalskills GS ON S.SkillId = GS.SkillId
    Where GS.LearningInstanceId in ('f968f7fe-25d9-4c3f-9a4d-d49c820c9b56','f968f7fe-25d9-4c3f-9a4d-d414520c9b56') ;

END
```

If you see the above query, in the `WHERE` condition, I passed 2 values, those values should come from C#, it will be the input parameter for this SP.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `WHERE LOCATE(GS.LearningInstanceId, @id) > 0`

Comment: @Mark, Locate is working like a charm, Thanks for the reply, really appreciated!!!